# Sending multiple emails with PHPmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

*Edit: I forgot I'd created the `SendMail();` function myself, which is why the explanation doesn't mention at first what it does.*

I'm having some trouble with PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) when attempting to send two emails, one directly after the other.

The script is almost completely 'out of the box', with only a few modifications such as a `foreach` loop to allow for multiple addresses, and everything still works perfectly.

However, if I attempt to call more than one instance of `SendMail();` I get the error message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot override final method Exception::__clone() in .... online 0
```

Previously I was using the in-built `mail();` function, which allowed me to use it as many times as I liked in quick succession , but it doesn't appear to be that simple with PHPmailer:

```
$to = me@me.com;
$to2 = me2@me2.com';
$headers = 'php headers etc';
$subject = 'generic subject';
$message = 'generic message';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
mail($to2, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The above would result in two identical emails being sent to different people, however I can't easily replicate this functionality with PHPmailer.

Is there a way of stacking these requests so that I can send successive emails without it failing?  Forcing the script to wait until the first email has been sent would also be acceptable, although not preferential.

As I mentioned I know it works when only one instance is called, but I don't seem to be able to re-use the function.

I haven't included the source code, although it is all available on the link provided above.

Thanks in advance

**Edit as requested**

```
// First Email
$to = array(
'test@test.com',
 'test2@test.com',);
$subject = "Subject";
$message = $message_start.$message_ONE.$message_end;

sendMail();

// Second Email
$to = array(
'test@test.com',
 'test2@test.com',);
$subject = "Subject";
$message = $message_start.$message_TWO.$message_end;

sendMail();
```

The above is how I want this to work, as it would work with `mail();`.  The first email will work fine, the second will not.

**SendMail() code**

This is from the PHPmailer website, and is what is defined as `SendMail();`.  The only difference from the example is the loop for `AddAddress`, and the inclusion of `$to` as a global variable.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "jswan";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "secret"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "from@example.com";
$mail->FromName = "Mailer";
foreach($to as $to_add){
$mail->AddAddress($to_add);                  // name is optional
}
$mail->AddReplyTo("info@example.com", "Information");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");         // add attachments
$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");    // optional name
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
```

Comment: Are you using the **same** `PHPMailer` object to send the two emails? You have to create a completely different `PHPMailer` object for the second email, or you could just use `AddAddress` to send the same email to multiple addresses. If you don't want the senders to see each other, use BCC.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you or not, but I've had this bookmarked and use it any time I use PHPMailer: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/send-email-from-a-page/using-phpmailer-to-send-mail-through-php

Comment: I wanted to re-use the same object, yes, but I have also attempted to create `SendMail2` as a separate function and run them one after the other.  They still use the same file - class.phpmailer.php, so would I also have to duplicate everything to do with the function?

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, I have it working as a single function but re-using the function is what causes the problem.

Comment: Why don't you post your *broken* code for PHPMailer and not just the code that actually works for you.. I suspect you may not be working with the `PHPMailer` object properly. We can look at the example code for PHPMailer all you like but you're clearly not writing your code exactly like the examples.

Comment: As I said, I know fully well that the PHPMailer code works because it works flawlessly when only calling one instance of it.  Therefore there is no broken code, only working code that is the same as the source code.  The code I have written is nothing to do with PHPMailer, it just demonstrates the functionality I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: Yes but I want to see how you're re-using the function and applying PHPMailer to your own programming methodology. If your code wasn't broken you wouldn't be getting an exception. You're likely re-using the object and this class has an exception to prevent `Send` from being called twice with the same object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Multiple Mails In PHP Mailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598921/sending-multiple-mails-in-php-mailer)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I'm asking asking if I can make this code work in the way I've described, which is to send two emails one after the other with similar content.

Comment: Okay, now what about your `sendMail()` function? What's the code for that? PHPMailer doesn't have a function like this, so you've probably defined your own.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot I'd made that into a function. I've updated the example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You haven't posted this code that lets me make this a complete conclusion, but from the Exception and the way you've defined an overriding class inside a function, you probably have `class.phpmailer.php` loading every time like this:

```
require('class.phpmailer.php');
```

or

```
include('class.phpmailer.php');
```

You should change that line to

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
```

The reason you need to change it to `require_once` is so that PHP will not load the class file the second time when you try to create the new/second `PHPMailer` class. Otherwise, the line `class PHPMailer` throws the `__clone()` exception.

Comment: PHPMailer now provides an autoloader and you should use that in preference to loading classes explicitly, just `require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';` and it will go and find any other classes it needs.

Comment: Thanks. That was it.

Answer (score 5):

Added an example below:

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows how to send a message to a whole list of recipients efficiently.
 */

//Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

//Passing `true` enables PHPMailer exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$body = file_get_contents('contents.html');

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = 'yourname@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'yourpassword';
$mail->setFrom('list@example.com', 'List manager');
$mail->addReplyTo('list@example.com', 'List manager');

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Simple database mailing list test';

//Same body for all messages, so set this before the sending loop
//If you generate a different body for each recipient (e.g. you're using a templating system),
//set it inside the loop
$mail->msgHTML($body);
//msgHTML also sets AltBody, but if you want a custom one, set it afterwards
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

//Connect to the database and select the recipients from your mailing list that have not yet been sent to
//You'll need to alter this to match your database
$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysqli_select_db($mysql, 'mydb');
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, 'SELECT full_name, email, photo FROM mailinglist WHERE sent = FALSE');

foreach ($result as $row) {
    try {
        $mail->addAddress($row['email'], $row['full_name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Invalid address skipped: ' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . '<br>';
        continue;
    }
    if (!empty($row['photo'])) {
        //Assumes the image data is stored in the DB
        $mail->addStringAttachment($row['photo'], 'YourPhoto.jpg');
    }

    try {
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message sent to :' . htmlspecialchars($row['full_name']) . ' (' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . ')<br>';
        //Mark it as sent in the DB
        mysqli_query(
            $mysql,
            "UPDATE mailinglist SET sent = TRUE WHERE email = '" .
            mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql, $row['email']) . "'"
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Mailer Error (' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br>';
        //Reset the connection to abort sending this message
        //The loop will continue trying to send to the rest of the list
        $mail->getSMTPInstance()->reset();
    }
    //Clear all addresses and attachments for the next iteration
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution, @amir.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Amr most excellent code.
In order to use this in a cron fasion, two adds are useful.

```
$mail-> SMTPDebug = true;
$mail-> Debugoutput = function( $str, $level ) {_log($str);};
```

The function _log is up to you. Writing to a file, to a database or wherever. I personally have reduced this to

```
$mail-> Debugoutput = function( $str, $level ) {if( $level===3 ) {_log( $str ); } };
```

to only write the more juicier messages

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to reset recipients data like this:

```
$Mailer->clearAddresses()
```

use your own variable as an instance of PHPMailer (instead of $Mailer)

Answer (score 0):

$Mailer->clearAddresses()

This is the solution to avoid multiple msj to be send to the same recipient.