# PHPMailer - sending email with a function

Tags: php, phpmailer

I need to send emails when users do particular things like fill in a form, submit a request etc. These happen on different pages.

I know the default use of PHPMailer is as below:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('myfriend@example.net', 'My Friend');
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

Is it possible to use the mail() class without having to re-specify the username, password and message to the mail function each time??

Essentially could you have a fuction like:

```
sendMail($from, $to, $subject, $body);
```

Which then passes the variables given to an instance of PHPMailer?

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908580/sending-multiple-emails-with-phpmailer).

Comment: Like having an own mailer class and get once the object and set once the username, password and message and then reuse the object to sendMail ?

Comment: I think you could create your own mail class extends of the PHPMailer and you specify the username and password only once inside it and after that you can use your own class everywhere without set credentials again and again.

Comment: I'm going to try this.

Comment: you can create a your own custom function which will have static credentials set in it and will email using php mailer.then use this function everywhere you want

Comment: Ok, it was an only an example but it is maybe safer to store any credentials outside of the root in a separate file or environmental variable in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
class MyMail extends PHPMailer
{
    private $_host = 'your stmp server name';
    private $_user = 'your smtp username';
    private $_password = 'your password';

    public function __construct($exceptions=true)
    {
        $this->Host = $this->_host;
        $this->Username = $this->_user;
        $this->Password = $this->_password;
        $this->Port = 465;
        $this->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $this->isSMTP();
        parent::__construct($exceptions);
   }

   public function sendMail($from, $to, $subject, $body)
   {
      $this->setFrom($from);
      $this->addAddress($to);
      $this->Subject = $subject;
      $this->Body = $body;

      return $this->send();
  }
}
$m = new MyMail();
$result = $m->sendMail('test@test.hu', 'youremail@yourdomain.com', 'Test from script', 'test message from script');
```

Comment: *"I think"* answers should be a comment.

Comment: Yes, I rewrite it a concrete code example for demonstration